# How to update Jupyter Book website link hosted on github pages

Tags: github-pages, jupyterbook

I created a Jupyter Book and hosted it on github. The website link is something like -

```
<github page>/_build/html/index.html
```

What config setting can I change to make the website link -

```
<github page>/index.html
```

Comment: This sounds more like a GitHub Pages issue than anything else, but you have not tagged it as such.

Comment: Yes, the [tag:github-pages] tag seems more relevant than [tag:python], for example.